# working with no string case in switch javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to use a switch for conditional problems.
condition:

if there is no value, message 1 appear,

if it is not a number, message 2 appear.

```
var c = document.getElementById("input3").value;
var message1 = "You have not input any data";
var message2 = "Please input only number";

switch (c) {
    case "":
        window.alert(message1);
        break;
    case (isNaN(c)):
        window.alert(message2);
        break;
    default:
        document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = c;
}
```

it doesn't work for the non-number condition. anybody can help?

Comment: `switch` is not what you need on this case. You can use `if` / `else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `true` to switch, then you can write an expression for each case.

If the expression evaluates to true the case will be used.

```
switch (true) {
  case c === "":
    window.alert(message1);
    break;
  case isNaN(c):
    window.alert(message2);
    break;
  default:
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = c;
}
```

```js
var c = document.getElementById("input3");
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var message1 = "You have not input any data";
var message2 = "Please input only number";

button.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const value = c.value
  switch (true) {
    case value === "":
      window.alert(message1);
      break;
    case isNaN(value):
      window.alert(message2);
      break;
    default:
      document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = value;
      c.value = ''
  }
}, false)
```

```html
<input id="input3" />
<button id="button">click me</button>
<p id="p2"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use "if else"

```
if(c == ""){
   window.alert(message1);
}else if(isNaN(c)){
   window.alert(message2);
}else{
   document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML=c;
}
```

Comment: i'd like to try 'switch'